# How to print text in different ways in the same program in python?

Tags: python, input, text

I'm making a text based game and my text currently types out letter by letter but for one specific scenario during the game I want it to show up all at once.

This is the part of the code that allows it to show up letter by letter

```
import time 
import sys 
import keyboard 

def print(s):   
   for c in s:
       if keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl"):
           sys.stdout.write(c)
           sys.stdout.flush()
       else:
           sys.stdout.write(c)
           sys.stdout.flush()
           time.sleep(0.025)
```

it also allows the user to press CTRL while the text is showing up to immediately show the rest of the text so they don't have to wait.

Now anytime I use print like this

```
print ("sample text")
```

the text show up letter by letter which is fine for the majority of the game except for this part

```
    print ("sample text")

input("\n[Press enter to continue]\n")

    print ("*KNOCK*")
```

Ideally I want the knock to show up immediately.

If I use an input like this

```
input ("*KNOCK*")
```

the text does show up immediately but the user has to press enter to get the next part.
Ideally I just want it to move on to the next print section automatically

What would be my best solution?

Comment: Modify the print function to have a second parameter, say x, if x is True then print normally otherwise print letter by letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call it `print`, since that overwrites the built-in `print` function. Just call it something else and then you'll be able to use `print` to show things instantly. You could name it something like `print_characters_individually`.